# Extracting URLs from NSString into NSMutableString

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I have a file with the following content:

```
cool name http://myurl1.tld/subdir/dir/var/ awesome\nanother cool name http://sub.domain.tld/dir/ nice\nsome nice name http://myname.tld/var/folder/ some\n
```

I read the file with this Objetive-C code:

```
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"../files/name.ext"]];
NSString* raw = [[NSString alloc]
                 initWithBytes:[data bytes]
                 length:[data length]
                 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

To extract all URLs from the above sample I use:

```
NSDataDetector* detector = [NSDataDetector dataDetectorWithTypes:NSTextCheckingTypeLink error:nil];
NSArray* matches = [detector matchesInString:raw options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [raw length])];
```

My goal is to append all extracted URLs into one single string and separate them with a semicolon (without any other stuff from the file) with this loop:

```
NSMutableString *allURLStrings = [NSMutableString string];
for (NSString *s in matches) {
    [allURLStrings appendString:s];
    [allURLStrings appendString:@";"];
 }
```

Whenever I try to run the code I get the following output:

> terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException (lldb)

I tried to use the loop like this, but then the `substringForCurrMatch` only contains a slash (/):

```
NSMutableString * allRepoString = [NSMutableString string];  
for (NSTextCheckingResult *s in matches) {
        NSString* substringForCurrMatch = [s.URL path];
        [allRepoString appendString:substringForCurrMatch];
        [allRepoString appendString:@";"];
    }
```

When I inspect `s` in the loop it shows me the correct object:
[image: contenct of s]

Is there a way to get this code working?

EDIT complete error message:

```
2016-08-11 23:00:19.272 AppName[34831:2892247] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[fetchurlsource allURLStrings]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x14c55ea00'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x181fa2db0 0x181607f80 0x181fa9c4c 0x181fa6bec 0x181ea4c5c 0x1000e8b6c 0x1000e8ee0 0x187100c40 0x187100844 0x18710759c 0x187104a88 0x18717afa4 0x1873a63ac 0x1873aa5f0 0x1873a7764 0x1839437ac 0x183943618 0x1839439c8 0x181f5909c 0x181f58b30 0x181f56830 0x181e80c50 0x18716f94c 0x18716a088 0x1000edb10 0x181a1e8b8)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

Comment: Which line does it throw the exception on ?

Comment: @Paulw11 [allURLStrings appendString:s]; the first one in the loop

Comment: Is there any more information with the exception message? It looks you should append `s.absoluteString` not just `s` since s is an NSURL

Comment: @Paulw11 I've added the complete error message. Sorry that I forgot that when I postet the question!

Comment: Set an exception breakpoint to confirm the line. That exception says it crashed somewhere where you accessed a method/property `allURLStrings` on an instance of `fetchurlsource`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None of the code you posted so far can result in the exception you posted.

But the following code is incorrect:

```
NSMutableString * allRepoString = [NSMutableString string];  
for (NSTextCheckingResult *s in matches) {
    NSString* substringForCurrMatch = [s.URL path];
    [allRepoString appendString:substringForCurrMatch];
    [allRepoString appendString:@";"];
}
```

You do not want to call the `path` method on `s.URL`. To get the full URL as a string, use `absoluteString`. This will give you the URL as a string. `path` just gives you the path portion of the URL.

```
NSMutableString * allRepoString = [NSMutableString string];  
for (NSTextCheckingResult *s in matches) {
    NSString* substringForCurrMatch = [s.URL absoluteString];
    [allRepoString appendString:substringForCurrMatch];
    [allRepoString appendString:@";"];
}
```